# JComponents not displaying properly

Tags: java, swing

My two jbuttons displayed on my JFrame are not displaying properly after I changed the colors of the JButtons. The text overlaps each other as i hover my mouse over.

Here's my code for the program:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class ButtonExample extends JFrame
{
   public static void main (String [] args) 
  {
    //Create jframe
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(400, 250);
    frame.setLocation(5, 5);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    
    //Create first button
    JButton button = new JButton("First button");
    button.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
    button.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 250));
    frame.add(button);
    
    //Create second button
    JButton button2 = new JButton("button 2");
    button2.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
    button2.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 250));
    frame.add(button2);
   }
 }
```

And here's the output of the program

Program when I first run it:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdPpK.png]

Program after I hover my mouse over both buttons:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFOvs.png]

Comment: Your transparent background for the buttons seems to be the problem. Set their background color to the same value as the JPanel if you want the buttons to blend in

Comment: @R VISHAL same problem occurred no matter what background color i set the Jbutton to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the button to be transparent then don't set the background.

Instead you can use:

```
button.setOpaque( false );
```

Now Swing will automatically paint the parent component first before painting the button so painting artifacts will be removed.